# Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: javafx

Пробую разбираться с javaFX.Выбрасывает вот таки ошибки.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:465)
at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1380)
at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$12(ContextMenuContent.java:1333)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3876)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Scene.java:3604)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2613)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1784)
... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2459)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
at gui.application.manager.main.MainManagerController.createOrder(MainManagerController.java:120)
... 54 more
```

Мой Main.java

```
package runner;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    private static Stage window;

public static Stage getMainStage() {
    return window;
}

public static void setMainStage(Stage window) {
    Main.window = window;
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    window = primaryStage;
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../gui/authorization/authorization.fxml"));
    window.setTitle("Авторизация");
    window.setScene(new Scene(root, 466, 300));
    window.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}
}
```

LoggingInstructions.java

```
package server;

import client.Client;
import gui.application.manager.main.MainManagerController;
import gui.application.mechanic.main.MainMechanicController;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import runner.Main;

import java.io.IOException;

public class LoggingInstructions {
    public void executeAuthInstructions(String serverAnswer) {
        String[] command = serverAnswer.split("/");
        switch (command[0]) {
            case "Ошибка Авторизации":
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                alert.setTitle(command[0]);
                alert.setHeaderText(null);
                alert.setContentText("Неправильный логин иили пароль");
                alert.showAndWait();
                break;
            case "механик":
                try {
                    Parent root;
                    MainMechanicController mainMechanicController;
                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../gui/application/mechanic/mainMechanic.fxml"));
                    root = loader.load();
                    Main.getMainStage().setScene((new Scene(root, 900, 700)));
                    mainMechanicController = loader.getController();
                    mainMechanicController.init("Механик: " + command[2],"ID Механика: "+command[1]);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case "менеджер":
                try {
                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                    Parent root;
                    MainManagerController mainManagerController;
                    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../gui/application/manager/main/mainManager.fxml"));
                    root = loader.load();
                    Main.getMainStage().setScene((new Scene(root, 900, 700)));
                    mainManagerController = loader.getController();
                    mainManagerController.init("Менеджер: " + command[2],"ID Менеджера: " + command[1]);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
        if(!command[0].equals("Ошибка Авторизации")){
            Client client=Client.getInstance();
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 1; i < command.length; i++) {
                sb.append(command[i]+"/");
            }
            sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);
            client.setClientInfo(sb.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

MainManagerController.java

```
package gui.application.manager.main;

import entity.Car;
import entity.Purchase;
import gui.application.manager.order.OrderController;
import gui.application.mechanic.main.MainMechanicController;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import runner.Main;
import server.CommandsExecuter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainManagerController {
    private CommandsExecuter commandsExecuter;
    @FXML
    private Label managerLabel;
    @FXML
    private ImageView managerImage;
    @FXML
    private Label managerID;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Car> carTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Car, Integer> carCode;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Car, String> carBrand;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Car, String> carModel;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Car, Integer> carYear;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Car, String> carEngineType;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Car, Double> carEngineCapacity;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Car, String> carColor;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Car, Integer> carPrice;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Purchase> orderTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Purchase, Integer> purchaseNumber;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Purchase, Integer> carID;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Purchase, Integer> clientID;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Purchase, Integer> employeeID;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Purchase, String> purchaseDate;


    public void init(String manager, String userID) {
        commandsExecuter = new CommandsExecuter();
        managerLabel.setText(manager);
        Image image = new Image(new File("images/manager.jpg").toURI().toString());
        managerImage.setImage(image);
        managerID.setText(userID);
        /*MenuItem mi1 = new MenuItem("Создать заказ с выбранным автомобилем");
        mi1.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
                Car item = carTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        });
        ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
        menu.getItems().add(mi1);*
        carTable.setContextMenu(menu);*/

    }

    @FXML
    private void getCarList() {
        ObservableList<Car> carList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        commandsExecuter.getCarList());
        carCode.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("carID"));
        carBrand.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("brand"));
        carModel.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("model"));
        carYear.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("year"));
        carEngineType.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("engineType"));
        carEngineCapacity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("engineCapacity"));
        carColor.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("color"));
        carPrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));
        carTable.setItems(carList);

    }
    @FXML
    private void getOrderList(){
        ObservableList<Purchase> purchaseList=FXCollections.observableArrayList(commandsExecuter.getPurchaseList());
        purchaseNumber.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("purchaseID"));
        carID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("carID"));
        clientID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("clientID"));
        employeeID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("employeeID"));
        purchaseDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("date"));
        orderTable.setItems(purchaseList);
    }

    @FXML
    private void closeApp() {
        Platform.exit();
    }
    @FXML
    private void createOrder(){
        Parent root;
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../gui/application/manager/order/order.fxml"));
            Stage orderStage = new Stage();
            root = loader.load();
            orderStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 700, 400));
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

mainManager.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<Pane prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="900.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="gui.application.manager.main.MainManagerController">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="managerLabel" layoutX="220.0" layoutY="36.0" text="Менеджер:">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold Italic" size="18.0" />
         </font></Label>
      <Button fx:id="closeButton" layoutX="610.0" layoutY="647.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#closeApp" text="Выход">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font></Button>
      <ImageView fx:id="managerImage" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="27.0" layoutY="36.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../../../images/manager.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Label fx:id="managerID" layoutX="220.0" layoutY="80.0" text="Label">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold Italic" size="18.0" />
         </font></Label>
      <TabPane layoutX="27.0" layoutY="204.0" prefHeight="496.0" prefWidth="850.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
         <tabs>
            <Tab text="Автомобили">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <ToolBar prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="850.0">
                           <items>
                              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#getCarList" text="Получить список автомобилей" />
                              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#getCarList" text="Обновить список автомобилей" />
                           </items>
                        </ToolBar>
                        <TableView fx:id="carTable" layoutY="35.0" prefHeight="433.0" prefWidth="850.0">
                           <columns>
                              <TableColumn fx:id="carCode" prefWidth="109.0" text="Код автомобиля" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="carBrand" prefWidth="125.0" text="Марка" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="carModel" prefWidth="104.0" text="Модель" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="carYear" prefWidth="108.0" text="Год выпуска" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="carEngineType" prefWidth="116.0" text="Тип двигателя" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="carEngineCapacity" prefWidth="118.0" text="Объём двигателя" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="carColor" prefWidth="84.0" text="Цвет" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="carPrice" prefWidth="85.0" text="Цена" />
                           </columns>
                           <contextMenu>
                              <ContextMenu>
                                <items>
                                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#createOrder" text="Создать заказ" />
                                </items>
                              </ContextMenu>
                           </contextMenu>
                        </TableView>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </content>
            </Tab>
            <Tab text="Заказы">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <ToolBar prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="850.0">
                           <items>
                              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#getOrderList" text="Получить список моих заказов" />
                              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#getOrderList" text="Обновить список моих заказов" />
                           </items></ToolBar>
                        <TableView fx:id="orderTable" layoutY="35.0" prefHeight="433.0" prefWidth="850.0">
                           <columns>
                              <TableColumn fx:id="purchaseNumber" prefWidth="170.0" text="Номер покупки" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="carID" prefWidth="170.0" text="Код автомобиля" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="clientID" prefWidth="170.0" text="Код Клиента" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="employeeID" prefWidth="170.0" text="ID менеджера" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="purchaseDate" prefWidth="170.0" text="Дата" />
                           </columns>
                        </TableView>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </content>
            </Tab>
         </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Не могу понять почему вылетает это ошибка и не запускается новое окно.Помогите

Comment: постарайтесь уменьшить количество кода, в таком никто разбираться не захочет

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй сделать следующие изменения в коде, где ты пытаешься загрузить fxml  mainManager.fxml, в классе LoggingInstructions.java

после `getClass()` вызови метод `getClassLoader()`

```
loader.setLocation(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("../gui/application/manager/main/mainManager.fxml"));
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем пофиксили это таким образом: в классе MainManagerController.java в методе createOrder поменял это

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("../gui/application/manager/order/order.fxml"));
```

на это

```
 FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(OrderController.class.getResource("order.fxml"));
```